# native UI component GLSurfaceView renders as a transparent box with red borders

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, react-native

I am trying to create a native UI component for android in React Native.
The component, for now is a basic GLSurfaceView with a yellow background.

```
package com.test2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

public class StitchSurface extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

public StitchSurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}


public StitchSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
    setEGLConfigChooser(false);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setRenderer(this);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

}


@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

}

I extended the SimpleViewManager

```
public class StitchSurfaceViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<StitchSurface> {
private static final String REACT_CLASS="RCTStitchSurface";
/**
 * Subclasses should return a new View instance of the proper type.
 *
 * @param reactContext
 */
@Override
protected StitchSurface createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new StitchSurface(reactContext);
}

/**
 * @return the name of this view manager. This will be the name used to reference this view
 * manager from JavaScript in createReactNativeComponentClass.
 */
@Override
public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
}
```

}

and implemented the ReactPackage

```
public class StitchSurfaceViewPackage implements ReactPackage {
@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
            new StitchSurfaceViewManager()
    );
}
```

}

after Registering the Module in MainActivity.java and Implementing the JS module, when I use it in my index.android.js,
The GLSurfaceView renders as an empty box with red border.
[Custom GLSurfaceView with dimension specified in a Stylesheet as (400,400)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZdm3.png)

Could you tell me what I could do to solve this?
The GLSurfaceView should render as a view with Yellow Background color.

Comment: It just started working by itself :/ I did nothing but try running the code after a good night's sleep :P